# i need to turn int into string and i have a problem in negatives and zero

Tags: c

the code is supposed to get an integer from the user and turn it into a string and the first place in the string needs to be the type of the number(lower then zero - higher the zero + and zero with that simple nothing)

```
#define GIVE_ME_THE_RIGHT_ARRAY_SIZE 2
#define MAX_INT_LENGTH_IN_C 10
char numberType(int number);

int  main(void)
{
    int number=0;
    char string[MAX_INT_LENGTH_IN_C]={0};
    char memoryString[MAX_INT_LENGTH_IN_C]={0};
    printf("Enter num: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    if(number>0){
    string[0]='+';
    }
    sprintf(memoryString,"%d",number);
    for(int i=0;memoryString[i]!=0;i++ )
    {
        string[i+1]=memoryString[i];
    }
    printf("string: %s length: %d",string,strlen(string));
}
```

Comment: `MAX_INT_LENGTH_IN_C 12` (to include `+/-` and the trailing `'\0'`). It is currently too short by 2. Forget `string` and just use `"%+d"` as the conversion specifier in `sprintf`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to use all the loops and multiple arrays just to ensure the `+/-` before the number output as a string. `sprintf` provides the flag `'+'` that can be included along with the *conversion specifier* to place the `+/-` before the integer converted, e.g.

```
    sprintf (memoryString, "%+d", number);
```

Additionally, you cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return***. Putting those pieces together, and providing the proper *conversion specifier* for `size_t` (e.g. `"%zu"`), your code reduces to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INT_LENGTH_IN_C 12

int  main(void)
{
    int number=0;
    char memoryString[MAX_INT_LENGTH_IN_C] = "";

    printf ("Enter num: ");
    if (scanf("%d",&number) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    sprintf (memoryString, "%+d", number);

    printf ("memoryString: %s length: %zu\n",
            memoryString, strlen(memoryString));
}
```

(**note:** as mentioned in the comment, you must `#define MAX_INT_LENGTH_IN_C 12` to account for the largest integer values, e.g. `-2147483648` with the `+/-` and providing room for the `'\0'` at the end)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/memorystring
Enter num: 432198
memoryString: +432198 length: 7

$ ./bin/memorystring
Enter num: -432198
memoryString: -432198 length: 7
```

Look things over and let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Your solution is really good and I'd use it in each real project, no down vote from me. ;-) However, it does not address the requirement for zero: no sign at all. (Who ever wants this, but some teachers tend to ask for silly stuff.)

Comment: Yes, you can include that with a simple `if(number >= 0)` conditional to output from `memoryString + 1` instead of  `memoryString` ignoring the `+/-` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

all I had to do is do an if-else check as shown below and add an int type function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define GIVE_ME_THE_RIGHT_ARRAY_SIZE 2
#define MAX_INT_LENGTH_IN_C 10
#define FIRST_PLACE 0
char numberType(int number);

int  main(void)
{
    int number=0;
    char string[MAX_INT_LENGTH_IN_C]={0};
    char memoryString[MAX_INT_LENGTH_IN_C]={0};
    printf("Enter num: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    string[FIRST_PLACE]=numberType(number);
    sprintf(memoryString,"%d",number);
    if(string[FIRST_PLACE]=='+')
    {
        for(int i=0;memoryString[i]!=0;i++ )
        {
        string[i+1]=memoryString[i];
        }
    printf("string: %s length: %d",string,strlen(string));
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;memoryString[i]!=0;i++ )
        {
            string[i]=memoryString[i];
        }
        printf("string: %s length: %d",string,strlen(string));      
    }
}

char numberType(int number)
{
    char type= 'a';
    if(number>0)
    {
        type='+';
    }
    if(number<=0)
    {
        type=' ';
    }   
        return type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all of this:

```
if(number>0){
string[0]='+';
}
sprintf(memoryString,"%d",number);
for(int i=0;memoryString[i]!=0;i++ )
{
    string[i+1]=memoryString[i];
}
```

With this:

```
const char* optional_prefix = (number>0) ? "+" : "";
sprintf("%s%d", optional_prefix, number);
```

Or simply:

```
sprintf(string, "%s%d", ((number>0) ? "+" : ""), number);
```